# bind event to iframe's content and trigger it from iframe

Tags: jquery, html, events, dom, iframe

I have isolated very strange bug from our current project:

[index.html](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dkw0k4.html) (demo) and [iframe.html](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dkw073.html)

do:

1) click at the first input and select any date

you will see - **"datepicker changed inside iframe!"**

2) click at the second input, write some symbols and press at any free space at the page

you will see - **"usual_input changed inside iframe!" + "usual_input changed outside iframe!"**

inside iframe:

```
<input id="datepicker" /> <input id="usual_input" />
```

binded at index.html to the change event at this inputs:

```
$(this).contents().find("#datepicker").change(... (1)
$(this).contents().find("#usual_input").change(... (2)
```

binded at iframe.html to the change event at this inputs:

```
$("#datepicker").change(... (3)
$("#usual_input").change(... (4)
```

But **№1** dont work in any browser!

jquery ui's datepicker **trigger change event 100% correctly**. why we cant bind to it **outside** an iframe?

Comment: `$(this).contentWindow.$("#datepicker")...` and also for usual_input?

Comment: it dont works at all. jquery contents() selects dom elements correctly. there is no bug here. bug is in events

Comment: Whoops I meant `$(this)[0].contentWindow.$("#datepicker")`, just try it, as what it returns isn't equal to what the `.find()` returns...

Comment: it works! please paste it as answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the window element of the iframe by:

```
$(this)[0].contentWindow.$("#datepicker")
```

Or this *might* work too:

```
this.contentWindow.$("#datepicker");
```

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

very intesting conclusion:

there are **2 jquery objects: main_$ and iframe_$**

main_$ can control iframe_$

iframe_$ cannot control main_$

iframe_$ cannot trigger events to main_$

**main_$(iframe).contents().find("element").bind("event"); will not work**

only standart (input, select and textarea)'s **events sended by browser can be catched anywhere**

best solution finded by **JCOC611** is to replace temporarily main_$ by iframe_$

```
var main_$ = $;
$ = $(iframe).get(0).contentWindow.$;
//many logick which works perfectly without iframes
$ = current_$;
```

you can of course use main_$ and iframe_$ independently

PS

dont remember very old jquery bug in the worst browser in the world - ie

```
$("...").find("iframe").ready(
    function() {
        //this == iframe.contentDocument
        this.contentWindow == undefined;
    }
);
```

get iframe's window only by specific path

```
$("...").find("iframe").get(0).contentWindow
```

and it work cross-browser! :3