# Triggering an event handler on an element inside iframe from parent frame

Tags: jquery, iframe, event-handling

I have a html page. Inside it I use jQuery to attach click event on a link. Then I use iframe to reference this html page from another page. However I could not trigger the event attached on that link with js (when I click the link with the mouse, the event gets triggered with no problem). How can I trigger that event from parent frame? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
var frame = $('#mainFrame'); // the iframe I am trying to access
var link = $('a.btn', frame.contents()); // the element is found correctly
link.trigger('click');  // nothing happens. 
var e = link.data('events');  // e is undefined.
```

Comment: Does the frame in the same domain?

Comment: yes. all under localhost for now

Comment: I understand that I could not do it for cross-site-script, but can I do it for the same domain?

Comment: Ok I found a post here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266377/bind-event-to-iframes-content-and-trigger-it-from-iframe).  If I use `frame[0].contentWindow.$('a.btn').trigger('click')` it will work. Anyone could point me the difference?

Comment: does my answer below solved your problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
document.getElementById('ifrmMsg').contentWindow.$('a:first').trigger('click');
```

- **Demo:** http://jsbin.com/aYijiLe/2
- Parent: http://jsbin.com/aYijiLe/2/edit
- iFrame: http://jsbin.com/IrogeBi/1/edit

You can also use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) for this purpose. It will work **cross-domain** as well. However JS inside the iframe must listen to the `message` event, i.e. you need to control the source of the iframe.

- **Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ILAsEmE/1
- Parent: http://jsbin.com/ILAsEmE/1/edit
- iframe: http://jsbin.com/uZEQuTa/2/edit

Comment: Excellent examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just place onload() event inside the iframe tag.

```
<iframe src="http://myURL.com" onload="myFunction()">
```