# Trigger a button click inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is the iframe code:

```
<div id="OutDiv" class="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="InnerIframe" class="FrameCSS" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the HTMl code of the button which the iframe above is calling:

```
<button type="button"  id="SuperWebF1" title="Continue" class="button">Continue</button>
```

Here is the jQuery function that i use to trigger the click of the button when page is loaded:

```
 $('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );
```

But this is working like that only when i place the jQuery code inside the source of button and the iframe is calling the button with the script.

I want to make an event which is clicking the button from outside the iframe.
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(function(){
    $('#InnerIframe').contents().find('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );
 });

Comment: #CodingAnt i've tryied your advice but it seems it's not working. The button is not clicked.

Comment: **Not a duplicate** of that question. This question is about GENERATING an event. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3672726/673991) is about INTERCEPTING an event. (I changed the title of that question; it was misleading and seemed like a duplicate.) Here it's all about `.trigger()`. There it's all about `.click(function...`

Comment: Oh wait, this is a **duplicate of** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032074/triggering-an-event-handler-on-an-element-inside-iframe-from-parent-frame  which appears to be the original. Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928860/jquery-to-trigger-a-click-on-an-iframe   And another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008226/trigger-click-inside-an-iframe

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**NOTE: .contents() does not work if iframe's src points to cross domain page. More: [Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) and [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)**

```js
//execute code after DOM is ready
$(function() {

  //find iframe
  let iframe = $('#main_iframe');
  
  //find button inside iframe
  let button = iframe.contents().find('#main_button');
  
  //trigger button click
  button.trigger("click");
  
});
```

```html
<!--Add jQuery library-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to manipulate another page inside iframe, search for official API or GET parameters.
Example: [Youtube Embed Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), [Google Maps Embed Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

Comment: Code only answers without an explanation of why that code should be considered typically aren't acceptable here. Can you edit to add an explanation of why you feel this answers the question?

Comment: Worked great for me

Comment: Can You provide a browser support or some kind of an official source please?