# Crawl a website with iframe

Tags: html, iframe, web-crawler

I have a test project using a library supporting crawl(openbuilding spiderling). 
The problem is when i crawl on url "https://examlple.com". This page content a iframe from "https://iframe.com".

I want to get the element p(s) inside the iframe. But i now only can get those elements by visit iframe.com. I want to know that is there anyway to get element p even when i don't visit iframe.com, such as wait for ifame loaded.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot spider an `iframe`'s contents from the parent page. The closest you can do is note the URL of the `iframe` and then go off and independently spider it.

Think of an `iframe` as a sandboxed and protective container that only lets you visually view its contents and nothing more - no spidering or talking to it (unless you own the page and are working with JavaScript `Window.postMessage()` etc.

Comment: what about this though? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332339/trigger-a-button-click-inside-an-iframe