# Display DialogBox at full scree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using frameset in my html page and inside that frameset there are two frames. First frame has a button which on click will show dialog box. The problem is that the dialog box is coming only in top frame and not on the full screen. Is there any way I can hide the frames on click of button and show popup on full screen.

root.html

```
<html
<frameset id="foo" rows="100,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="frame1" scrolling="no" src="frame1.html" >
        <frame name="frame2" scrolling="yes" src="frame2.html">
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

frame1.html

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http:/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>

      function showDialog()
      {
var f  = parent.document.getElementById('foo');
    alert(f);
        //parent.document.getElementsByTagName('frameset')[0].rows = "100%,0";
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      }

      </script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <p> Top Frame  </p>

      <button onclick="showDialog();">click Here </button> 

      <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

frame2.html

```
<html>
<body>
   Bottom Frame
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest putting your listener to open the dialog inside the parent (root.html) page, and then having the dialog itself in that page, also - so you can full-screen it to the `body` element of the parent. You can listen to events from within frames. See this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032074/triggering-an-event-handler-on-an-element-inside-iframe-from-parent-frame - although it does mention iframes, I'm sure this should still be the case for `frameset`'s `frame`s

Comment: from frame1.html javascript, var f  = document.getElementById('foo'); is giving null instead of some object. Any idea how can I get the object

Answer (score 0):

If you want some element on fullscreen, you can try js library like this [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/). Here is the demo page of that library [demo](https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/) to check if this is what you want to achieve