# Jquery 'mouseover' only before content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a function that should detect what you hover over *only* in a certain `iframe`. 
*The code*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    editor();
});
function editor(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe")
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    $(doc).on('mouseover',function(e){
      console.log("hey");
      //further code non-related
    });
}
```

It should fire when I move my mouse and I have my mouse over this certain `iframe`, but it only does it once when I load it and my mouse is in the `iframe`. Is there an update I am not aware of or? So, when I move my mouse over this `iframe` **nothing** happens, which is kind of upsetting *and* the problem.

---

**The target**

So, the initial goal is to have an `iframe` on a page and when I move my mouse over that `iframe` I want to be able to see what item *in* the `iframe` I'm hovering over. This is *only* when the mouse is *in* the `iframe`. I want to get that message when I'm hovering over the items *in* that `iframe` I suppose....

**When it does work**

It works, *without* content. As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u3ad53ug/2). *Butttt...* when content is loaded in, the whole operations shuts down and is **not** working anymore.

Comment: I tried it and it works properly. Maybe you want `mousemove` instead of `mouseover`?

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE those event will work if iframe is empty! As soon as content is loaded, it wont work!

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event on the **IFRAME DIRECTLY**

```js
function editor(){
    $("iframe").on('mouseover',function(e){
      alert("hey");
      //further code non-related
    });
}

editor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NMBNZspmn7I">

</iframe>
```

Comment: No, ok. I'm sorry to have confused you maybe, but I want to have it trigger when I hover the contents of that `iframe` not just the `iframe` on it's own. In essense step into the dimention of the `iframe` but then when hovering *anything* there it should send a message.

Comment: +you mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19812589/3563013

Comment: @McKabue Yes, but that is essentially what I was trying as you can see in my example above.

Comment: Ok, in the end my problem lies in the fact that I'm doing this local (not on a server) and then it just doens't work. Thanks, but your answer was *not* the answer... @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE came a lot closer. Actually, you had it, except that I had it on local...